# Создал проект Node в IDEA, вопрос по структуре

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

Создал проект Node в IDEA, вопрос по структуре, что куда класть, частично понятно, частично нет. 
П.С. Это первое знакомстве с Node Js.
Имею:
/bin/, /node_modules/, /public/, /routes/, /views/ Вроде все понятно,

но /bin/www содержит

```
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/
var app = require('../app');
```

который сбивает с толку, /app/ у меня нет.
Так где хранятся "модели", "контроллеры" и прочее back end?

Comment: А что Вы хоть создали? Если проект для сервера express, то модели и контроллеры не имеют никакого отношения к серверу, поэтому их и нет.

Comment: Ну да, судя по всему это express framework.

Comment: если быть точнее то сервер express, который к каким-либо парадигмам не имеет никакого отношения. А views это всего-лишь шаблоны шаблонизатора jade, ну или можно так же .html или что-то другое, не так важно. Ставите mongoos или ему подобный и вот Вам модель. Ну или гуглите архитектурные фраймворки, таким является sails.js